# How can I get this ajax request to post without error?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

Why is the following not working? I keep getting the following 500 error.

> "{"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: question.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()\r\n   at "

```
// button submit
    $('#btnCreatePoll').click(function ()
    {
        var fields = $('#createPoll input').serializeArray();       

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "PollManagerCreatePoll.aspx/test",
            data: fields,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg)
            {
                // Do something interesting with msg.d here.
            }
        });
    });




  [WebMethod]
    public static void test (object data)
    {
        string test = "test";
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you should give us an idea what `fields` is.

Comment: forget using fields. Send anything

Answer (score 1):

*"PollManagerCreatePoll.aspx/test"* doesn't make sense, unless you are using a URL rewrite to make *"PollManagerCreatePoll.aspx"* a directory. Do you mean *"PollManagerCreatePoll.aspx?test"* or *"PollManagerCreatePoll.aspx"*?

**EDIT:**
Did you even search Google first? A quick search found this:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/invalid-json-primitive-error-while-using-ajax

Comment: This is a technique for sending ajax request via jquery

Comment: Sounds like you need to figure out what what 'question' in 'Invalid JSON primitive: question' is.

Comment: link doesn't even work and I have searched Google quite extensively